# how to automate test in Cypress with Saucelab including performance testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, saucelabs

I am able to integrate cypress and sauce lab able to run the test successfully

[image]

but need to integrate the performance test with sauce https://docs.saucelabs.com/performance/analyze

How to run performance test on it?

need result like this https://docs.saucelabs.com/performance/analyze

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Sauce Labs doesn't support performance analysis when using Cypress.

Partly this is because the results wouldn't be that accurate; Cypress itself has an impact on the measurable performance of the browser.

This *may* change; the Sauce team has it under consideration (Source: I work there).